# Where has the community wiki button gone?

Tags: support, privileges, community-wiki

I've just been trying to make a question of mine community wiki.  I was expecting the button to be below the answer box, as described on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

> [image: community wiki button on SO page]

I definitely have more than 10 reputation, but I can't see the button. Screenshot from Firefox 32:

> [image: missing community wiki button]

Screenshot from Internet Explorer 11:

> [image: missing community wiki button, again]

In Firefox, I have the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) and [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/) add-ons installed.  Disabling them did not change my ability to see the button.

Has the button been moved/removed? Am I experiencing browser weirdness?  Am I being really stupid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CW button on questions has been gone for a long long time now.

I posted the exact same question 4 years ago:

[Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

Comment: I clearly didn't pay enough attention to the screenshots. I saw the first one was an answer and assumed the others were too!